# Why I got different result when using different `for loop` in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about `for loop` in js, here are examples:

In this part, `child` is `object` (what I want).

```
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = element.childNodes[i];
        console.log(typeof(child));
}
```

But when change the code, `child` become to `String`, valued `0, 1, 2 ...`

```
for (var child in element.childNodes) {
        console.log(typeof(child));
}
```

Why the two types of `for loop` got different results?
Thanks..

Comment: the second loop is looping through the keys. To obtain similar result you would need `element.childNodes[child]`

Comment: because the `for..in` loop iterates the enumerable keys of an object. Like `for(var key in object) ...`. you probably meant `for(var child of element.childNodes) ...`

Comment: You should use `of` instead of `in`

Comment: Why did you not use the `for (var i in element.childNodes) { var child = element.childNodes[i]; … }` pattern in the second snippet as well?

Answer (score 0):

"A `for...in` loop only iterates over enumerable properties." Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Said properties are just strings which i believe are the keys in your object.

Answer (score -1):

In a `for in` loop, you retrieve keys. The following should log the same as your first loop:

```
for (var child in element.childNodes) {
  console.log(typeof(element.childNodes[child]));
}
```